# How to customise the dialogs that a user sees when she runs my windows forms setup project?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, setup-project

I have to create a *setup project* for my windows form application and I want to change the *default computer picture*(it contains a monitor placed on a CPU along with a keyboard, mouse, CD and has purple background) which appears in the *top right corner* of all of the *installation screens*. I want to replace it with bmp image which we have created. What is the procedure to do this? Please note that I am working on .Net 2.0, visual studio 2005. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Are [Visual Studio Setup Project - Use exe Icon for installed Shortcuts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758171/visual-studio-setup-project-use-exe-icon-for-installed-shortcuts) and [Change Setup.exe icon in Setup Project](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/95963729-c3da-437d-a9ec-ebcd3011a22d/) of any help?

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't want to change the icon of the setup file. Neither do I want to change the desktop shortcut icon. Once we run the setup we can see many installation screens right, which take you throught the installation process. For instance, the first screen states "Welcome to the ...... Setup Wizard'. Now if you notice - on these screens on the top right corner there is an image which is basically a PC having a purple bg. It is this image that I want to change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Setup project selected, use View + Editor and click "User Interface".  You'll see a tree view of the dialogs that the user sees when she runs the installer.  Standard steps are Welcome, Installation Folder, Confirm Installation, Progress and Finished.

Select one of those steps and look in the Properties window.  Note the BannerBitmap property.  Change it from (Default) to your own custom bitmap.